# Possible way to prevent direct url access of PHP/HTML files using by showing and error or by redirecting

Tags: php

I have recently been able to hide the file extensions on my website using `.htaccess` , however I need to make sure that no one can visit any php/html file using the file extension on the url

Currently, my .`.htaccess` file looks like this

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: My recommendation would be to switch to a single simple router script, and then use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711319/231316) to only allow that file.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I want them to be able to visit the php/html files but without using the file extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting all URLs that end in .php to no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795590/redirecting-all-urls-that-end-in-php-to-no-extension)

Comment: @CBroe this method worked.. but however it doesn't submit any form on the site on submit

Comment: If you make an external redirect with 301/302/303 status code, then you will lose any POST data, because the browser will follow up by making a GET request. You could use 307 instead, in that case clients are not supposed to change the request method. But how is this an issue in the first place, do you need to receive data from forms that are _not_ under your control? In the ones that you are in control of, you should of course change `action="processingScript.php"` to `action="processingScript"` to begin with now.

Comment: I am making use of this `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"`